# Resta de ultimo trimestre del año actual con el trimestre de hace un año DAX en Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

tengo una tabla con los campos tarjeta,comercio,num-comercio,fecha-transaccion,conteo_transacciones,ocupo hacer una resta del promedio del año actual con el promedio de  hace un año en DAX power bi, ejemplo: el promedio del año 2023(enero,febrero y marzo) fue de 28.75%  y el año 2022(enero,febrero y marzo) fue de 22.90%  el resultado de la resta es de 5.85%, tambien ocupo que en la formula no se tenga que estar cambiando el año del forma manual ,todo sea automatico, otro ejemplo seria el promedio del  ultimo trimestre (nov-22,dic-23 y ene-23) fue de 25.65% y  el promedio de hace un año fue(nov-21,dic-21 y ene-22) fue de 20.35% el resultado es de 5.3%